# Theorem environment under polyglossia

Tags: polyglossia, ntheorem

How to set theorem header font to be normal+bold and theorem body font to be normal+italic in the example below? If I remove the lines starting with `\usepackage{fontspec}` and ending with `\newfontfamily{\serbianfonttt}{DejaVu Serif}`, then I get what I need.

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily{\serbianfont}[Mapping=ascii-to-serbian, Script=Cyrillic, Language=Serbian]{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily{\serbianfonttt}{DejaVu Serif}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} 


\usepackage{ntheorem}  
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}   


\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[section]

\begin{document}
    \begin{teorema}
        ssssssddd
    \end{teorema}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the main and mono font instead. If you want italics, use `\itshape` rather than `\slshape`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, b5paper]{book}

\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath} 

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{ntheorem}  
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}   

\setmainlanguage[Script=Cyrillic]{serbian}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}[
  Mapping=ascii-to-serbian,
  Script=Cyrillic,
  Language=Serbian,
]
\setmonofont{DejaVu Serif}

\theoremheaderfont{\normalfont\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[section]

\begin{document}

\begin{teorema}
abcde fghijk lmnop qrstu vwxyz
č ć š ž dj 
\end{teorema}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thx! But now if I insert sections, like \section{Sec}, I receive Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Cyrill(polyglossia) Please define \cyrillicfont with \newfontfamily. \section{Sec}    . In addition, after applying your suggestion,I have noticed a long time for compiling the whole document (200 pages) counting around 50 sec.

Comment: Me again. It seems that if I remove \usepackage{fancyvrb} and
\usepackage{inconsolata}, then it compiles without errors (I did not inspect which of them caused the problem). But still, compiling procedure is too long, which is very unplesent (before I applied your suggestion, it took around 7-8 sec).

Comment: @Zoran Your code loads neither `fancyvrb` nor Inconsolata. I get no error about `\cyrillicfont`.

Comment: I am speaking about the code in the whole document not in a short example. Anyway, I also noticed that if I insert \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathgot}{U}{euf}{m}{n} in the shortcode preamble, and $$\lim$$ in the document body, then I get lim written cyrilic (contrary to the previous situation).

Comment: @Zoran I understand that, but I can't see your bigger document.

Comment: OK, I supposed. The last commend was related to the shortcode, so if you or anyone could help, this would be verry appreciated. RgdeZS